# DNS for a cPanel addon domain to resolve to a dedicated IP address?

Tags: dns, cpanel, ip-address, magento, whm

I would like to know how to set the DNS of an addon domain in cPanel to resolve to its own dedicated IP address, not the IP address of cPanel parent domain.

Answer (score 2):

I received this answer from CPanel
This is not a feature that is supported in the WHM or cPanel frontend, however it is possible to change the ip address of an addon domain by manual editing.
Here is link to tutorial:
https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/How+to+Assign+Dedicated+IP+Addresses+to+Subdomains

Comment: If you're satisfied with your own answer, then please accept it to let others know that it's been resolved. Thanks.